# Linq query returns duplicate results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The following query returns duplicate results, in the second select query.

Country has `0..1 to *` relationship with leagues.

Leagues have `1 to *` relationship with userLeagues.

```
    return from ul in userLeagues
            select new Map.Country
            {
                id = ul.Country.CountryId,
                name = ul.Country.Common_Name,
                leagues =  userLeagues.Where(x => x.CountryId.Value == ul.CountryId.Value)
                                     .Select(x => new Map.League
                                     {
                                         id = x.LeagueID,
                                         name = x.leagueNameEN,
                                     })

            };
```

I tried using `Distinct` with no luck.
It seems that either i have to use distinct or groupby countryId

The output is such as

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Europe",
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Champions League",
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europa league",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Europe",
    "leagues": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Champions League",
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europa league",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe try adding `.ToList()` on the end of the query you're assigning to `leagues`. But what do you mean by "duplicate"? Are you saying every country gets all the userleagues, or every country gets all the userleagues belonging to the last country, or what?

Comment: duplicate on which columns/properties?

Comment: Can you not use group by to remove duplicate results?

Comment: @Neel This one seems to be my huge issue. I tried but...

Comment: So what you want to do is select all the countries, selecting each country *once*. And for each distinct country in that query, you want to select the leagues that belong to it. Try `from ctry in userLeagues.Distinct(ul => ul.Country) select new Map.Country { ctry.CountryID ... etc.`

Comment: Looks like you need to simply group `userLeagues` by `Country`. Or start from Country table and use navigation property or `GroupJoin` with `UserLeagues`. In general you should provide your entity model classes when you have EF related question.

Comment: Sure. Looks like if you start from `Country`, there will not be dupliucates and group by will be needed. The only thing which is unclear to me is the purpose of the `UserLeagues` - are you filtering by `UserId`?

Comment: Actually it's interesting to see what your `userLeagues` variable does contain. If you don't filter by `UserId`, it's normal to have duplicates. In other words, the duplicate results in your query come from `userLeagues query`, not the inner `select` subquery.

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually the user leagues contains just two columns. The userId and the leagueId. The filtering and the response you see above is based on the leagues the user has selected.

Comment: Anyway, I think you already got 2 answers covering my initial comment - group by query (tomassino) and country based query (WellerEE). I personally prefer to avoid group by when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group it by `CountryId` and `Common_Name` to get expected results:

```
var result = from ul in userLeagues
             group ul by new { ul.Country.CountryId, ul.Country.Common_Name } into g
             select new Map.Country
             {
                 id = g.Key.CountryId,
                 name = g.Key.Common_Name,
                 leagues = g.Select(x => new Map.League
                 {
                     id = x.LeagueID,
                     name = x.leagueNameEN,
                 })
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're doing: For each league in `userLeagues`, you're creating a `Map.Country` for the country that league belongs to. If three leagues are in France, that's three Frances. France is a wonderful country, but let's not go overboard.

Instead, you want to start with a distinct list of countries. For each one, create one `Map.Country`, and give that `Map.Country` a list of the leagues that should belong to it.

First, let's make `Country` implement `IEquatable<Country>` for `Distinct` purposes:

```
public class Country : IEquatable<Country>
{
    public bool Equals(Country other)
    {
        return other.CountryID == CountryID;
    }
```

Second, you want to start with a distinct list of countries, and then populate them with leagues.

```
var q =
    from ctry in userLeagues.Select(ul => ul.Country).Distinct()
    select new
    {
        id = ctry.CountryID,
        name = ctry.Common_Name,
        leagues = userLeagues.Where(x => x.Country == ctry)
                             .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 id = x.LeagueID,
                                 name = x.leagueNameEn
                             }).ToList()
    };
```

I didn't recreate your `Map.League` and `Map.Country` classes, I just used anonymous objects, and I left it that way because this code definitely works just as it is. But filling in your class names is trivial.

If it's not practical to make `Country` implement `IEquatable<T>`, just write a quick equality comparer and use that:

```
public class CountryComparer : IEqualityComparer<Country>
{
    public bool Equals(Country x, Country y)
    {
        return x.CountryID == y.CountryID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Country obj)
    {
        return obj.CountryID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

...like so:

```
var cc = new CountryComparer();

var q =
    from ctry in userLeagues.Select(ul => ul.Country).Distinct(cc)
    select new
    {
        id = ctry.CountryID,
        name = ctry.Common_Name,
        leagues = userLeagues.Where(x => cc.Equals(x.Country, ctry))
                             .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 id = x.LeagueID,
                                 name = x.leagueNameEn
                             }).ToList()
    };
```

This is logically equivalent to a `GroupBy`, which is probably a more respectable way to do it. But somebody else thought of that before I did, so he earned the glory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the you need to reverse your query.  So instead of starting with userLeagues, start with country and include the child leagues.